# Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdServices.framework/AdServices | Reason: image not found

Tags: ios

Incident Identifier: 7EBC5316-1217-477F-96B7-C1725C2A3641
Hardware Model: iPhone8,2
Process: PalaceMaster [9085]
Path: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10F7686F-17B6-4AFF-B8F1-BE0568D1E7A2/PalaceMaster.app/PalaceMaster
Identifier: com.cookie.palace.en
Version: 16 (2.0.12)
AppStoreTools: 12D4d
AppVariant: 1:iPhone8,2:9
Code Type: ARM-64 (Native)
Role: Foreground
Parent Process: launchd [1]
Coalition: com.cookie.palace.en [1695]

Date/Time: 2021-02-07 20:28:59.4500 -0500
Launch Time: 2021-02-07 20:28:59.4098 -0500
OS Version: iPhone OS 12.0 (16A366)
Baseband Version: 5.10.00
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXCCRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXCCORPSENOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdServices.framework/AdServices | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/10F7686F-17B6-4AFF-B8F1-BE0568D1E7A2/PalaceMaster.app/PalaceMaster | Reason: image not found
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x0000000103384264 abortwithpayload + 8
1   dyld                            0x00000001033838a4 abortwithpayloadwrapperinternal + 100 (terminatewithreason.c:71)
2   dyld                            0x00000001033838d4 abortwithpayload + 12 (terminatewithreason.c:93)
3   dyld                            0x00000001033448f4 dyld::halt(char const*) + 312 (dyld.cpp:4024)
4   dyld                            0x00000001033477cc dyld::main(machoheader const*, unsigned long, int, char const, char const, char const**, un... + 5468 (dyld.cpp:6519)
5   dyld                            0x0000000103341044 dyldstart + 68

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x000000016d89e990   x3: 0x00000000000000b5
x4: 0x000000016d89e590   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000600
x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x0a72657473614d65  x11: 0x6e6f736165522020
x12: 0x20200a7265747361  x13: 0x203a6e6f73616552  x14: 0x6f6e206567616d69  x15: 0x00646e756f662074
x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000000000010  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
x20: 0x000000016d89e590  x21: 0x00000000000000b5  x22: 0x000000016d89e990  x23: 0x0000000000000001
x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x00000001033a7000  x27: 0x00000001033a7aa0
x28: 0x00000001033a79e0   fp: 0x000000016d89e560   lr: 0x00000001033838a4
sp: 0x000000016d89e520   pc: 0x0000000103384264 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x102560000 - 0x102f67fff PalaceMaster arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/10F7686F-17B6-4AFF-B8F1-BE0568D1E7A2/PalaceMaster.app/PalaceMaster
0x103340000 - 0x1033a3fff dyld arm64  <8f53711b46f3359ea4d6479c85ada9ce> /usr/lib/dyld

EOF

I've commented out "useframeworks!"
and
This crash is not a sure thing, but there have been 8 cases in a week, mostly ios12.

Answer (score 4):

`AdServices.framework` is available on ios 14.3+.
if your device system is bellow 14.3(ios 14.2, ios 14.1, ios 14.0 ...) then your app will be crashed. (I know this is xcode bug, not is your wrong. but we need do something)

Let set the AdServices.framework is `optional`

[image]

Comment: Saved my life, thanks. BTW, I also need to make the AppTrackingTransparency.framework optional, and I have to introduce a "LinkPresentation.framework", and mark it as optional, to make the app run on ios 12